# Run C++ Executable on Linux Server Using PHP

Tags: php, c++, linux

I have a C++ binary on my hosted server (hosted with Arvixe FYI). I have a form on my website that takes 3 inputs. I take those 3 inputs and put them in a file using PHP. I am trying to call my C++ application from within PHP. The application takes 2 parameters the first is the file with the inputs and the second is the file where I want the output to go.

The application works fine on my Mac when I run using terminal but it is not running when I put it on the hosted server.

Here is the PHP code in my script:

```
$user =  JFactory::getUser();
$time_date = date("m-d-Y").time();
$file1 = "model1_".$user->id."_".$time_date."_input.txt";
$file2 = "model1_".$user->id."_".$time_date."_output.txt";
$path1 = "/home/hhansen/public_html/ads/".$file1;
$path2 = "/home/hhansen/public_html/ads/".$file2;

$file_handle = fopen($path1,'w'); 

$content  =  trim($_POST['form']['Input 1'])."\r\n";
$content .= trim($_POST['form']['Input 2'])."\r\n";
$content .= trim($_POST['form']['Input 3'])."\r\n";

fwrite($file_handle,$content);
fclose($file_handle);

$output = exec("/home/hhansen/public_html/ads/./model1 $path1 $path2",$retval);
```

Can someone please shed some light? The input file is being created directly. I do have execute permissions on the application within the server. I'm not sure if the executable isn't running at all or if it's just not producing the output because of a permissions issue or something.

- Is it my syntax?
- Am I using the wrong function?
- What should I be using in PHP to send commands to the terminal and execute this?

Comment: Did you compile it to a Linux binary?  You can't just copy&paste from Mac to Linux.  The binary is "model1", correct?

Comment: Correct. That might be my problem. Is there anyway I can compile it to a Linux binary on my Mac?

Comment: I think it's architecture dependent, however there are [cross-compiling techniques](http://www.gc-linux.org/wiki/Cross-compiling).  I have no experience doing it my self, but it looks like gcc/g++ would be a good solution.  There's also this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#GCC_and_cross_compilation).

Comment: Maybe I should just compile it on a linux box right? You think this will solve my problem?

Comment: As long as the architectures match.  If they don't use the same [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_instruction_sets) your server won't know what to do with it.

Comment: I know my hosting company uses CentOS on all their servers so maybe I can compile on a CentOS box and be in good shape?

Comment: Sorry, it's not that simple.  If you have cPanel, it says on the left side bar, along with your PHP, and Apache versions.  It would be "i686" or "x86_64" or something like that.

Comment: I know. I'm saying assuming the binary compilation was the problem then compiling in the same OS in the same architecture should solve my problem. And it is x86_64. I'll download CentOS and try it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most commercial shared hosts run PHP in safe mode, which disallows exec() or at least restricts it to special directories. Check with a simple executable.

Comment: exec() is allowed and safe mode is not enabled.